# Kendo Upload Dropzone

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, kendo-ui, upload

I'm using kendo upload to let the user upload their files and I also allow them to upload files by drag and drop the file to a specific zone(#dropZoneArea). Everything is fine and working in chrome except IE. I know drag and drop are not work in IE 9 and below but I'm using IE11.

This is my code for the kendo upload:

```
        $("#files").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: "upload.aspx?request=upload",
                removeUrl: "removeurl",
                autoUpload: true,
                allowmultiple: true
            },
            localization: {
                select: "Select Files"
            },
            validation: {
                maxFileSize: 1048576
            },
            complete: onComplete,
            success: onSuccess,
            progress: displayLoading,
            error: function (e) {
            },
            dropZone: "#dropZoneArea",
            showFileList: false
        });
```

Anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Can you please specify on what error ocurrs in internet explorer? Thx :)

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some JavaScript error?